# Best solution to save videos from a mobile application (Android)

Tags: android, mobile, video, service

I'm working on an Android application that records video which then gets uploaded and stored on a server but I don't have idea where can I save this files. There are any solution like Heroku, Appfog or OpenShift, where I can store a large amount of files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about [s3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/), [or rackspace cloud files](http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/files/), or any other cloud storage solution.

Comment: I was searching for one free solution with "GB limit" but suppose that S3 will be the best option to start because I can'n find anything better.